# Hooks doesn't expose `try_on_runtime_upgrade`?

Tags: runtime-upgrade, storage-migration, on-runtime-upgrade

If defining migrations in structs that impl `OnRuntimeUpgrade`. And these structs are then put into a Tuple migration, pre and post-upgrade hooks are noops on the tuple.
See [this issue](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/13681).

The idea being that we should use `try_on_runtime_upgrade` instead.

1. This is poorly documented.
2. If we want to call `try_on_runtime_upgrade` from the pallet, it's not exposed in the `Hooks`, only the `pre_upgrade` and `post_upgrade` hooks are exposed. See [here](https://paritytech.github.io/polkadot-sdk/master/frame_support/traits/trait.Hooks.html).

Is there something I'm missing here? How should they be called?

Edit for some more info:

In our pallets we have (just using pre_upgrade for simplicity, but post is the same):

```rust
#[cfg(feature = "try-runtime")]
fn pre_upgrade() -> Result<sp_std::vec::Vec<u8>, DispatchError> {
    migrations::PalletMigration::<T>::pre_upgrade()
}

// in migrations .rs

pub type PalletMigration<T> = (
    VersionedMigration<crate::Pallet<T>, v4::Migration<T>, 3, 4>,
    VersionedMigration<crate::Pallet<T>, v5::Migration<T>, 4, 5>,
    VersionedMigration<crate::Pallet<T>, v6::Migration<T>, 5, 6>,
    VersionedMigration<crate::Pallet<T>, v7::Migration<T>, 6, 7>,
);
```

`VersionedMigration` impls `OnRuntimeUpgrade`, with `on_runtime_upgrade`, `pre_upgrade` and `post_upgrade` definitions.

Which then calls the inner migration e.g. `v5::Migration`. So it's just a wrapper which does a couple of things like version checking.

`v5::Migration` impls `OnRuntimeUpgrade`, and contains the storage migration logic.

So, in the pallet, if we just call `pre_upgrade` on the tuple migration, (aliased to `PalletMigration` it doesn't work. It's a noop.

So we're only implementing the pre and post upgrade hooks, but they don't trigger.

Our Executive definition looks like:

```
pub type Executive = frame_executive::Executive<
    Runtime,
    Block,
    frame_system::ChainContext<Runtime>,
    Runtime,
    AllPalletsWithSystem,
    (),
>;
```

Comment: My understanding is pre and post hooks are to implements tests for try-runtime and the upgrade code to execute on chain goes into OnRuntimeUpgrade

Comment: @Simson yeah, that's how we're using it. The upgrade code is in `on_runtime_upgrade()` part of the hook, and just the pre and post checks are in the `pre_upgrade` and `post_upgrade` hooks. Currently if I run `try-runtime on_runtime_upgrade` the upgrade runs, but the hooks do not.

Comment: Did you put it in the `pub type Executive = frame_executive::Executive<` ?

Comment: Put what in there? I added our Executive definition to the OP

Comment: 1 sec I will write it in an answer

Comment: Perfect @liamaharon updated their answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`try_on_runtime_upgrade` is used only internally by the Executive pallet: (https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/ea4085ab7448bb557a1558a25af164cf364e88d6/substrate/frame/executive/src/lib.rs#L372).

You should not try to override this method. You only need to implement `pre_upgrade` `post_upgrade` and `on_runtime_upgrade`. Executive handles the rest.

**Edit based on extra info you provided**

You need to pass `PalletMigration` as the last parameter to `Executive`

```rust
pub type Executive = frame_executive::Executive<
    Runtime,
    Block,
    frame_system::ChainContext<Runtime>,
    Runtime,
    AllPalletsWithSystem,
    PalletMigration, // <-- here
>;

// can nest them if you like

pub type Executive = frame_executive::Executive<
    Runtime,
    Block,
    frame_system::ChainContext<Runtime>,
    Runtime,
    AllPalletsWithSystem,
    Migrations,
>;

pub type Migrations = (
    PalletMigration,
    OtherMigrations,
    SomeMoreMigrations
)
```

Comment: Added some more context in an edit to the issue, as this is what we're doing currently.